# How to create a new list item with FLOWR and XQuery?

Tags: grouping, data-extraction, xmltable, flwor, shred

I'm looking to select non-numerical data from an `XML` file towards shredding it into database columns, or at least an `xmltable`-like structure.  This `FLWOR` gives a somewhat useful result:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";

<ul>
{
for $foo  in db:open("foo")
return <li>{$foo//text()[not(matches(., '[0-9]'))]}</li>

}
</ul>
```

However, it outputs **all results** into a single `li` tag, like:

- a b c d

Preferred output would be of the form:

- a
- b

Most likely the [data is problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221464/262852) in some way, because a slightly different `FLOWR`:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";

for $foo in db:open("foo")
return $foo//text()[not(matches(., '[0-9]'))]
```

certainly outputs each non-numerical string on a new line.  How can I output this into a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested)?

An excerpt of the data:

```
 <table:table-column table:style-name="co1" table:default-cell-style-name="ce17"/>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro1">
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="ce15" office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>John Smith</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
  </table:table-row>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro2">
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="ce16" office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>(123) 456-7890</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
  </table:table-row>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro2">
    <table:table-cell office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>123 Main Street</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
  </table:table-row>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro2">
    <table:table-cell office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>Anywhere, ZZ 12345-6789</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
  </table:table-row>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro1">
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="ce15" office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>Jane Doe</text:p>
    </table:table-cell>
  </table:table-row>
  <table:table-row table:style-name="ro2">
    <table:table-cell table:style-name="ce16" office:value-type="string" calcext:value-type="string">
      <text:p>(234) 567-8901</text:p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an `li` for each of the `text()`, then alter what you are iterating over. Instead of selecting the `text()` inside of the for loop, iterate over each of the `text()`:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";

<ul>
{
for $foo  in db:open("foo")//text()[not(matches(., '[0-9]'))]
return <li>{$foo}</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only for completeness:

output:

- people
- joe
    phone1
    phone2
    phone3
- sue
    cell4
    home5
- alice
    atrib6
    x7
    y9
    z10

query:

```
xquery version "3.0";
declare namespace office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0";

<ul>
{
for $line in db:open("people")//text()
return
      if (matches($line, "[0-9]"))
      then <ul>{$line}</ul>
      else <li>{$line}</li>
}
</ul>
```

Should this benefit anyone else.