# How to transform nested XML to CSV?

Tags: xml-parsing, xquery, basex, xmltable, flwor

While not strictly `XML` at [this point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60229052/262852), looking to transform a "list" into something which would work for `XML` shredding, so something more like a table.  Suitable for import to a spreadsheet or a table in a `SQL` database.

How would this input:

- people
- joe
    phone1
    phone2
    phone3
- sue
    cell4
    home5
- alice
    atrib6
    x7
    y9
    z10

get transformed to a structure like:

```
joe phone1 phone2 phone3
sue cell4 home5
alice atrib6 x7 y9 z10
```

It only matters that the "names" are in the first column, other "attributes" in any of following columns of `CSV` or similar, or something exportable as such `CSV`.  It *doesn't* have to be `CSV`, perhaps just convertible to such a structure because `BaseX` exports to `CSV` quite nicely through the `GUI`.

or, perhaps:

```
joe phone1 
joe phone2 
joe phone3
sue cell4 
sue home5  
alice atrib6 
alice x7 
alice y9 
alice z10
```

Although I prefer the former for this specific data.

Answer (score 4):

I think in another question you already got the suggestion to use `windowing`:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";

declare option output:method 'text';
declare option output:item-separator '&#10;';

for tumbling window $group in ul/*
start $s next $n when $s[self::li] and $n[self::ul]
return
    tail($group) ! ($s || ',' || .)
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVSgeS