# how to add a flat text file to BaseX?

Tags: xml, database, nosql, command-line-interface, basex

What does it mean "content is not allowed in prolog"?  Perhaps the input method needs to be set first?  I'm trying to add data to an empty database in `Basex` with [dummy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60221464/262852) data as below:

```
thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$ 
thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$ basex
BaseX 9.0.1 [Standalone]
Try 'help' to get more information.
> open people
Database 'people' was opened in 199.0 ms.
> 
> add to people /home/thufir/flwor/people/people.txt
"/home/thufir/flwor/people/people.txt" (Line 2): Content is not allowed in prolog.
> 
> exit
Have a nice day.
thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$ 
thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$ cat people.txt 

a
1
2
3
b
4
5
6
c
7
8
9

thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$
```

I could make it `CSV` or other, but would like to use just plain text.

Certainly it can be added through the GUI as:

[image: added]

Selecting the file:

[image: adding resource]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was perhaps a silly question:

```
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size    Input Path                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
dummy                1          21119                                            
foo                  1          167152  /home/thufir/basex/foo/foo.fodt          
people               1          4610                                             
text                 1          55302   /home/thufir/Desktop/text.txt            
twitter              45         366800                                           
w3school_data        1          5209    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

7 database(s).
> drop database people
Database 'people' was dropped.
> 
> create database people
Database 'people' created in 79.03 ms.
> 
> open people
Database 'people' was opened in 0.05 ms.
> 
> set parser text
PARSER: text
> 
> add to people /home/thufir/flwor/people/people.txt
Resource(s) added in 9.18 ms.
> 
> list
Name                 Resources  Size    Input Path                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
com.w3schools.books  1          6290    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml  
dummy                1          21119                                            
foo                  1          167152  /home/thufir/basex/foo/foo.fodt          
people               1          4610                                             
text                 1          55302   /home/thufir/Desktop/text.txt            
twitter              45         366800                                           
w3school_data        1          5209    https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml   

7 database(s).
> 
> exit
Have fun.
thufir@dur:~/flwor/people$
```