# How to return a range of XML nodes with XQuery of FLWOR?

Tags: xml, syntax, xquery, basex, flwor

I'm interested in getting back a specific range of results, say from 99 to 199, or, [perhaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60259916/262852), the last `JSON` object.  While this works for small numbers or ranges, how can it be generalized or expanded to a larger range?

```
xquery version "3.0";

for $i in (1,2,3)
for $line in db:open("json_people")
return $line/json/_[$i]
```

Comment: It’s not clear to me what you want to achieve. Most of all, I am confused about the naming of your variables. Does `db:open` really return lines? Could you please replace the database function with an XML snippet that allows us to run your code without further modifications?

Comment: it wasn't anything specifically, just to get a range of results.  The `line` is a bad name, yes.  I kept trying from (99..199) or other variations but couldn't find the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the nested loop, use the `position()` function and specify a range:

```
db:open("json_people")/json/_[position() = 99 to 199]
```

Comment: Or if you prefer, `subsequence(db:open("json_people")/json/_, 99, 100)`. Note that once again, fixating on finding a FLWOR expression to do this doesn't actually help you.

Comment: fair enough, @MichaelKay  -- I was also taking the opportunity to learn flwor a bit and at the same time didn't want stray.

Answer (score 1):

You can use range in XQuery as follows:

```
for $i in (99 to 199)
```